# i am stuck in one line return statement for this problem

Tags: python, string, function, list-comprehension

The highlight_word function changes the given word in a sentence to its upper-case version. For example, highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice") returns "Have a NICE day". Can you write this function in just one line?

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
return(___)

print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
print(highlight_word("Shhh, don't be so loud!", "loud"))
print(highlight_word("Automating with Python is fun", "fun"))
```

can only write that line in the return statement nowhere else.

Comment: `.upper()` on the string should work.

Comment: I'd recommend `re.sub`.  You'll have to play around a little with the regular expression to account for punctuation, words that are substrings of other words, etc.

Comment: replace the word with its uppercase version, what have you tried?

Comment: That's a very artificial requirement. Is this homework? Regardless of that, what have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: You'll want to split the string on whatever the word is, and then join with the upper'd word.

Comment: yeah but how to check the condition on return statement that if the word in sentence is the word we want to do upper() how to do that with string i don't know can u please tell.

Comment: Look at the string methods `replace()` and `upper()`.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat - You don't need to check if the word is in the sentence at all, if its not there, then there is nothing to replace

Comment: how to split and then compare with the word to do  upper() and join in single statement that i want to knwo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem ?

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
  return sentence.replace(word, word.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
    return(sentence.replace(word,word.upper()))

print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
print(highlight_word("Shhh, don't be so loud!", "loud"))
print(highlight_word("Automating with Python is fun", "fun"))
```